# Multiple background using single url

Tags: css, background

hey this is my code for using 2 image in background but is it possible to use one url for both image insted of using 2 url .

`body {
    background-image: url(images/bgtop.png), url(images/bg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat;
}`

Comment: Try to read about CSS sprites - http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but it will involve more image manipulation in photoshop than actual css.

You'll have to turn your background into some kind of sprite, meaning you'll have to merge the backgrounds into one image. then use multiple different background-positions to display different parts of the image.

Sprite example: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp#gsc.tab=0

An example of multiple backgrounds, using different background-positions: http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/ Take note that this example has two separate images, so two separate URLs. You'll need to combine the use of different background-positions with the use of sprites.